# Interactive AMP list that can be updated based on response data

Tags: amp-html

I have been interested in moving an e-commerce website over to AMP and in following the progress this past year there have been a lot of improvements.

Adding items from an amp page is pretty straightforward, I can generate the data for the product through an end-point on my server. Then I can send an item add to an endpoint on my server with a form submission.

I can also return their current cart data and display that through an amp-list. However, I cannot include a form inside of an amp-mustache template in order to include a button to remove an item from the cart, or update item quantity.

Is it possible to have an interactive amp-list that can update when users add items and allows for users to update quantity and remove items from the list?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to Add to Cart functionalities. Check AMP's [Product Page](https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/product_page/#product-configuration) and click the Demo. You'll be using amp-list. Also, check out [amp-live-list](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-live-list), it provides support for content that is updated live on the client, so that the user can consume new information as it is available without having to refresh or navigate to a different page.

Comment: Hey noogui, the add to cart on the product page unfortunately doesn't have a live cart on that page. In there demo I cannot, at least I have seen how to, delete items or update item quantity for the items added.

Comment: if it's not there, it may not be supported yet.

Comment: I am sure there is a clever way to accomplish it with amp-bind or some other method. I was just curious if anyone has seen a working amp cart so I have more of a direction.